# Sort and Filter data from a Panda Dataframe according to date range

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

My dataframe has two columns: (i) a date column in a string format and (ii) an int value. I would like to convert the date string into a date object and then filter and sort the data according to a date range. Converting one string to a date worked fine with:

```
date = dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
date = ("%02d:%02d:%02d" % (date.hour, date.minute, date.second))
```

How can I iterate on all the values in the dataframe and apply the parsing so I can then use the panda library on the df to filter and sort the data as follows?

```
df.sort(['etime'])
df[df['etime'].isin([begin_date, end_date])]
```

Sample of my dataframe data is below:

```
          etime                        instantaneous_ops_per_sec
3    2016-06-15T15:30:09Z                         26
4    2016-06-15T15:30:14Z                         26
5    2016-06-15T15:30:19Z                         24
6    2016-06-15T15:30:24Z                         27
```

Comment: I think you might want `df['etime'].between(begin_date, end_date)` instead of using `isin` to do your filtering.  Using `isin` will only return `True` for dates that exactly match `begin_date` or `end_date`.  Using `between` will return `True` for dates that are inclusively between `begin_date` and `end_date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['etime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['etime'], format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
df[df['etime'].between([begin_date, end_date])]
```

Caution: Since your code says `date` and you use `time`  and then sort on `time`. The results may not be what you are after.  You usually want to filter then sort, But the code in OP does the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['etime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['etime'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I get the following error: 

    `df['etime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['etime'], format="%H:%M:%S")`


*time data u'2016-06-15T15:30:09Z' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)*

Comment: I get the same error, but it works for me without specifying a format: `pd.to_datetime(df['etime'])`.

Comment: Both suggestions worked: the format below or no format as root suggested - thanks!